# How to perform augemented DOE in R

Tags: r, experiment-design

I have run a series of experiments for a continuous relationship between a response (y) and a single covariate (x). The model for this relationship is probably somewhat logarithmic, so y = Beta log(x). I need to choose the design points for the next round. These points should be conditional on previous design points and their results to obtain a global best value for a design criterion, like the D criterion.

In JMP it is possible to do this with [Augemented Designs](https://www.jmp.com/support/help/14/augment-designs.shtml). Is there a similar function in R or a way to achieve it with a sequence of calculations (also fine)? I don't see this directly in AlgDesign, which I use often, and it is not clear to me if the new DOE.base package can do this.

Comment: Thanks, I did miss that. It seems though that it is for factors, and not augmentation for continuous functions. I've updated my question.

Comment: Why do you think it is only for factors? You specify which **rows** to keep! not which variables.

Comment: I must be missing something. Thanks for your help. It looks like optFederov wants input from gen.factorial, which produces levels like -1,0,1. When I test out in optMonteCarlo, I am able to use continuous variables.

Comment: optFederov just wants a matrix, it doesn't care how you made that matrix!

Comment: Thanks for your push. Here is some code for a dummy example. dat<-gen.factorial(104,1,varNames=c("X"))
dat$X <- c(0.1,.05,1,2,seq(2,4.40,length.out = 100))
desD<-optFederov(~log(X), nTrials = 6,dat,eval=TRUE, augment = TRUE, rows = c(1:4))

Answer (score 2):

This is supported in `AlgDesign`. Check the help pages for `optFederov`: It has two optional arguments, `augment` and `rows` which do what you ask for.

Below is a short example:

```r
library(AlgDesign)

M1 <- as.matrix( gen.factorial(2, nVars=4, varNames=LETTERS[1:4]))
M2 <- as.matrix(gen.mixture(11, 4))
colnames(M2) <- letters[1:4]

car_prod <- function(M1, M2) { # Cartesian product of two matrices
    ind  <- expand.grid(1:NROW(M1), 1:NROW(M2))
    rbind(cbind(M1[ind[,1],], M2[ind[,2],]))
}

M <- car_prod(M1, M2)

set.seed(7* 11* 13)
# Note we need to remove the intercept from the formula 
# because of the mixture vars
des <- optFederov(~ .-1, data=M, nTrials=16, maxIteration=1000, 
                         nRepeats=100)

# Now we want to augment this design:

des_aug <- optFederov(~ .-1, data=M, nTrials=32, augment=TRUE, 
                      rows=des$rows, maxIteration=1000, nRepeats=100)
```

But look at the solution! All the mixture variables has one mixture component at 1.0, which cannot be good ... so for practical use much more thought is needed, but this example shows the mechanics of use of R